# it is possible to make call on button click and show our own view rather then default?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want dial a number on button click and don't want to show that six options(sound,mute..etc) which are provided by iphone by default but i want to show my own view or option at calling time. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking to modify the phone calling screen then You can't....